# Change Webpack entryPoint using Plugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-hmr, webpack-plugin

I'm writing Webpack Plugin and I need to do the same trick [`HotModuleReplacementPlugin`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/webpack-3/lib/HotModuleReplacementPlugin.js) does in order to inject `webpack-hot-client` before the app.

It changes the entry-point of the bundle to be some custom function that requires `./node_modules/webpack-hot-client/client/index.js` and then loads the original entry app.

Snippet from the bundle

```
/***/ 0:
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

__webpack_require__("./node_modules/webpack-hot-client/client/index.js?ed7fa357-74e7-4924-8c07-8372aa814415");
module.exports = __webpack_require__("./app/index.js");

/***/ }),
```

I can't find the code that does that, any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've found the answer of how `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` does it, apparently it not the one that responsible for that.

`webpack-hot-client` changes the [entry point](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-hot-client/blob/35b69e506e6fcb9dc19f46e70d1d0e24d70f16b2/lib/util.js#L8-L34) to be an `Array` when the first item there is the `webpack-hot-client` script.

Webpack creates from that array an entry that looks like I've posted.